# Disable scrolling bars and enable scroll with mouse wheel and touch scroll only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to disable scrolling bars from the browser and allow user only to scroll the web using the mouse wheel and touch scrolling (in mobile devices) to move through the divs up and down?

Based in this idea:

HTML:

```
<style>
html, body {
height: 100%;   
}
div {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="div01" style="background: red"></div>
<div id="div02" style="background: blue"></div>
<div id="div03" style="background: green"></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var div01 = $("#div01");
var div02 = $("#div02");
var div03 = $("#div03");
div01.click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: div02.offset().top }, 1500);
}); 
div02.click(function() {
    $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: div03.offset().top }, 1500);        
});
```

That's the code with a click event to go to the next div, how can I change it to a mouse wheel and touch scroll instead of the click? And add the previous div code when scrolling up too?.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

It will work for you

```css
*{margin:0;}
#container-main{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container-sub{
    width: 100%;
    height: 99%;

    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

html, body{
    height: 99%;

    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-main"><div id="container-sub">
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
    hello<br/>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3<br/>
  
    good<br/>bye.
</div><div>
```